# Column calculations from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. First is HumanResources.Employees a the other is ProjectDetails.TimeCards b
I want the TotalCost column on ProjectDetailsTimeCards to automatically be calculated i.e. TotalCost=Billable Hours b * BillingRate a. they can be joined with the employee_ID. But i've not been able to put it into a table format.
The table are below

```
Create table HumanResources.Employees (
Employee_ID int primary key identity (99, 11),
First_Name char (20) not null,
Phone_Number varchar (30) not null
CONSTRAINT chk_Phone_Number CHECK (Phone_Number like '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
Title char (35),  
Billing_Rate int constraint chk_Billing_Rate check (Billing_Rate > '0')
); -- would be uses to multiply billing hours

create table ProjectDetails.TimeCards(
Time_Card_ID int identity (55,15) primary key,
Employee_ID int foreign key references HumanResources.Employees(Employee_ID), -- references primary key on the human_resources table
Date_Issued date,
Days_Worked int constraint chk_Days_Worked check(Days_Worked > '0'),
Project_ID int foreign key references ProjectDetails.Projects(Project_ID), -- foreign key reference
Billable_hours int constraint chk_Billable_Hours check (Billable_Hours > '0'),-- would be used to multiply billing rate
Total_Cost money, -- should automatically take TotalCost=Billable Hours b * BillingRate a
Work_Code_ID int foreign key references ProjectDetails.WorkCodes(Work_Code_ID)
);-- references primary key on another table
```

CREATE VIEW HumanResources.vwEmployeeData 
        AS
        SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.Date_Issued, e.Days_Worked, e.Project_ID, e.Billable_Hours, e.Work_Code_ID-- view from the first table
        FROM HumanResources.Employees e JOIN    ProjectDetails.TimeCards d
        ON e.Employee_ID = d.Employee_ID -- the view i created

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions; the last few the users have taken the time to do so for you. Your questions will be better received by users if you format them well. The last few questions all seem to have been related. Could you show you your attempt(s)to solve this problem yourself please? Stack Overflow isn't a free consultancy website, so please don't treat it as one. Try to solve the problem yourself, show your attempts. Like I said in your other question though,I suggest using a `VIEW` here. You can't have a calculated column based off another table.

Comment: Thanks for including the table DDL in your question. Please add the query you attempted too.

Comment: @LArnu thanks. I'm still relatively new here, i'm still learning the ropes so to speak. Yeah they are all related cos it's from a practice document i'm learning from. Would share my code now

Comment: What was wrong with the view? (Also, please do make your SQL as code so we can read it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining a function something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetValue(@billablehours INT, @empid INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
   SELECT @billablehours * e.Billing_Rate 
   FROM HumanResources.Employees e
   WHERE e.Employee_ID = @empid
```

After that you make a computed column

```
ALTER TABLE ProjectDetails.TimeCards
   ADD Total_Cost AS GetValue(Billable_hours, Employee_ID)
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. sorry to bother you but that's the error i get seems something is wrong. I added the begin next to as. but it now says incorrect syntax next to @empid

Comment: That's because it's a Scalar function, yet it trying to work like a table-value function, @Shayooluwah

Comment: However this solution works, it may have performance issue. just to be aware!

Comment: @Shayooluwah , I mean using function in computed column has performance penalty. If your dataset is small don't worry but if your data volume or user concurrency is high, you may have performance issue